# iOS - Can't add NSString objects to NSMutableSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

For some reason NSString objects just won't go into an NSMutableSet

The set remains empty - count stays 0 and firstInHandler is never called

I have tried everything..!

If anyone has any idea why I would greatly appreciate the help

---

VCKeySet.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VCKeySet : NSObject
{
    void (^firstInHandler)();
    void (^lastOutHandler)();
}

@property (atomic, readonly, strong) NSMutableSet* keys;

- (id) initWithFirstInHandler:(void(^)()) firstInHandler_ withLastOutHandler:(void(^)()) lastOutHandler_;

- (void) add:(NSString*) key_;
- (void) remove: (NSString*) key_;
- (BOOL) has: (NSString*) key;

@end
```

VCKeySet.m

```
#import "VCKeySet.h"

@implementation VCKeySet

@synthesize keys;

- (id) initWithFirstInHandler: (void(^)()) firstInHandler_ withLastOutHandler: (void(^)()) lastOutHandler_
{
    if(self=[self init])
    {
        firstInHandler = firstInHandler_;
        lastOutHandler = lastOutHandler_;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) add:(NSString*) key_
{
    for(NSString* key in self.keys)
    {
        if([key isEqualToString:key_])
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    [self.keys addObject:key_];

    if([self.keys count] == 1)
    {
        firstInHandler();
    }
}

- (void) remove: (NSString*) key_
{
    for(NSString* key in keys)
    {
        if([key isEqualToString:key_])
        {
            [keys removeObject:key];

            if([keys count] == 0)
            {
                lastOutHandler();
            }
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) has: (NSString*) key_
{
    for(NSString* key in keys)
    {
        if([key isEqualToString:key_])
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Here is how I try to add a key to the set

```
VCKeySet* lock = [[VCKeySet alloc] initWithFirstInHandler:^()
{
    NSLog(@"Adding UI lock");
    [application beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}
withLastOutHandler:^()
{
    NSLog(@"Removing UI lock");
    [application endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}];

[lock add:@"InitialiseApp"];
```

---

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to pretest to see whether or not the string is already in the set... `NSSet` does this.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `forin` loop on the remove method and just call `removeObject:`.

Comment: Ah cool I thought I would have to check the strings because they are different objects with the same string value but it seems to work without the manual check :) Does NSSet have some type checking to deal with strings in a special way or something?

Comment: Without even looking at the code I could tell you weren't creating the set.  Not being able to add anything to a array/dictionary/set (or retrieve from it) is a classic symptom of having a nil pointer to said array/dictionary/set.

Comment: Yeah silly mistake :) First I tried subclassing NSMutableSet I guess that's why I forgot to initialise it after turning VCKeySet into a wrapper

Comment: `NSSet` uses `isEqual:` to determine the equality of the object you're trying to add versus objects it already contains.  For `NSString`, `isEqual:` returns the same thing as `isEqualToString:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you never allocate and initialize your set.

Refactor your `add:` method to look something like this:

```
- (void) add:(NSString*) key_ {
    if (!self.keys) {
        _keys = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }

    [self.keys addObject:key_];

    if([self.keys count] == 1) {
        firstInHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the VCKeySet init method: if(self=[self init])
    {
        _keys = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

Comment: If you're going to "lazy load" the set like that it's better to write custom getters and setters that follow that logic, and then make sure you always use the property (`self.keys` or `[self keys]`) rather than the iVar (`_keys`). That way you can be sure that your code never tries to access a nil keys property.